# How to check if webform has a draft submission?

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm using hook_webform_submission_form_alter() to prepopulate some form values. When a user saves a draft of their webform submission and comes back to it later, the code in hook_webform_submission_form_alter() is wiping out their saved values. How do I first check if there's an existing draft submission? Using Webform 6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah found it...

```
function MYMODULE_webform_submission_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  $form_object = $form_state->getFormObject();
  $webform_submission = $form_object->getEntity();

  if ( $webform_submission->isDraft() ) {
    return;
  } else {

    //pre-populate fields...
  }  
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function MYMODULE_webform_submission_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Check if there's an existing draft submission.
  $webform_submission = $form_state->get('webform_submission');
  if ($webform_submission && !$webform_submission->isCompleted()) {
    // Get the saved values from the existing draft submission.
    $values = $webform_submission->getData();
    // Prepopulate the form fields with the saved values.
    $form['elements']['my_field']['#default_value'] = $values['my_field'];
    // Add any additional prepopulation code here.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but $form_state->get('webform_submission') is null.

Comment: It seems that the $form_state->get('webform_submission') value is currently null, which could mean that no webform submission has been made yet